# Placing a Property into a Different XML Namespace with XML Serialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio-2008, xml-serialization

I am using VSTS2008 + C# + .Net 3.0. I am using below code to serialize XML, here is my current code and serialized XML file. My purpose is I want to make MyInnerObjectProperties belongs to a special XML namespace (http://foo/2009) and making this namespace as default namespace. Any ideas how to implement this?

Current output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MyClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <MyObjectProperty>
    <MyInnerObjectProperties>
      <MyInnerObjectProperty>
        <ObjectName>Foo Type</ObjectName>
      </MyInnerObjectProperty>
      <MyInnerObjectProperty>
        <ObjectName>Goo Type</ObjectName>
      </MyInnerObjectProperty>
    </MyInnerObjectProperties>
  </MyObjectProperty>
</MyClass>
```

Current code:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private MyObject[] _myObjectProperty;

    [XmlElement(IsNullable=false)]
    public MyObject[] MyObjectProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return _myObjectProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            _myObjectProperty = value;
        }
    }
}
public class MyObject
{
    private MyInnerObject[] _myInnerObjectProperty;

    [XmlArrayItemAttribute("MyInnerObjectProperty", typeof(MyInnerObject),  IsNullable=false)]
    public MyInnerObject[] MyInnerObjectProperties
    {
        get
        {
            return _myInnerObjectProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            _myInnerObjectProperty = value;
        }
    }
}

public class MyInnerObject
{
    public string ObjectName;
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("foo.xml", FileMode.Create);
        MyClass instance = new MyClass();
        instance.MyObjectProperty = new MyObject[1];
        instance.MyObjectProperty[0] = new MyObject();
        instance.MyObjectProperty[0].MyInnerObjectProperties = new MyInnerObject[2];
        instance.MyObjectProperty[0].MyInnerObjectProperties[0] = new MyInnerObject();
        instance.MyObjectProperty[0].MyInnerObjectProperties[0].ObjectName = "Foo Type";
        instance.MyObjectProperty[0].MyInnerObjectProperties[1] = new MyInnerObject();
        instance.MyObjectProperty[0].MyInnerObjectProperties[1].ObjectName = "Goo Type";

        s.Serialize(fs, instance);

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: George, when did you stop using .NET 3.5 SP1?

Comment: John, I am working on several projects. Some of them are developed from scrach, and I will use .Net 3.5 SP1 + .Net 2.0 SP2. For legacy projects, I will keep its original .Net version. It is a pity that LINQ cannot be used in .Net 3.0 based projects. Any way, any ideas for my question?

Comment: I'm working on it. Someone will have the answer before me, I'm sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an **XmlSerializerNamespaces** object, and add your needed namespaces to it.

The [XmlSerializerNamespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializernamespaces.aspx) object contains the XML namespaces and prefixes that the XmlSerializer uses to generate qualified names in an XML-document instance.

In your c# code:

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces myNameSpaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
myNameSpaces.Add("MyInnerObject", "http://foo/2009");
```

Then, add an attribute to your class, like this:

```
public class MyInnerObject
{
[XmlElement(Namespace = "http://foo/2009")]
```

More info at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializernamespaces.aspx

Comment: Thanks Robert. My purpose is not adding everything of class MyClass into a unified namespace, but to add just MyInnerObjectProperties elements into namespace "http://foo/2009". I think your solution will add all elements from class MyClass into "http://foo/2009", correct? Any ideas to my issue?

Comment: You don't have to use it for the whole class.  You can pick and choose the elements and attributes you want.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializernamespaces.aspx

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
[XmlArrayItemAttribute( Namespace = "http://foo.com/2009" /* other attr. params. */ )]
public MyInnerObject[] MyInnerObjectProperties
{
    get { ... }
    set { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
public class MyObject
{
    [XmlArrayItemAttribute("MyInnerObjectProperty", typeof (MyInnerObject),
        IsNullable = false)]
    [XmlArray(Namespace = "http://foo.com/2009")]
    public MyInnerObject[] MyInnerObjectProperties { get; set; }
}
```

for me, this produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <MyObjectProperty>
        <MyInnerObjectProperties xmlns="http://foo.com/2009">
            <MyInnerObjectProperty>
                <ObjectName>Foo Type</ObjectName>
            </MyInnerObjectProperty>
            <MyInnerObjectProperty>
                <ObjectName>Goo Type</ObjectName>
            </MyInnerObjectProperty>
        </MyInnerObjectProperties>
    </MyObjectProperty>
</MyClass>
```