# Unwanted Property Name With XML Serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing Wrapper Elements from XML-Serialized Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227693/removing-wrapper-elements-from-xml-serialized-array)

This is difficult to explain so I am including an example of my problem. I have a parent class that contains a list of child classes. When I serialize the parent I am getting my child classes but they are under an element with the public property name. The extra level is not what I need. I tried adding the XmlIgnore attribute to the property name but that suppressed everything the property name and the collection of invoices it contained.

**Parent class:**

```
[XmlRoot("header")]
public class Lynx : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    #region /*-- Class Fields --*/

    private List<InvoiceItem> _invoice = new List<InvoiceItem>();

    #endregion

    [XmlArray("invoice")]
    [XmlArrayItem("invoice", typeof(InvoiceItem))]
    public List<InvoiceItem> invoice
    {
        get
        {
            return _invoice;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _invoice)
            {
                _invoice = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("invoice");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Child class:**

```
[XmlType(TypeName = "invoice")]
public class InvoiceItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ... properties and methods of the class
}
```

This is what it is building:

```
<header>
    <headerid>790aa61a-ad1b-49b9-bfb9-01fe3ca55eca</headerid>
    <invoice>  <-- this line is not needed
        <invoice>
            <company>BRU111</company>
            <format>myformat</format>
            ...
```

This is what I need to build:

```
<header>
    <headerid>790aa61a-ad1b-49b9-bfb9-01fe3ca55eca</headerid>
    <invoice>
        <company>BRU111</company>
        <format>myformat</format>
        ...
```

Comment: (removed my answer as @Tuzo found an excellent existing duplicate, but: use `[XmlElement("invoice")]` instead of your current attributes)

Comment: @Tuzo - Good find and thanks, I couldn't express the question well enough to find the other one.

Answer (score -1):

The reason the extra element is created is because your property is a List of items

If you want a singular value, use

public InvoiceItem invoice
{

instead of

public List<InvoiceItem> invoice
{

Collections always place a container, so that each item is placed under the container node.

Comment: The header element will contain 1+ invoice elements so I do want a collection of invoice.